# Suggestions for tag improvements

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Can the tagging system be improved?

I see a lot of questions asked with [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc). Could the editor suggest the correct tag [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) based on some community developed guideline? The keyword is suggest. Another example would be [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) would suggest [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf), [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms), etc.

Also, could we have a community driven tag blacklist? I think it would be beneficial that we could eliminate [general](/questions/tagged/general), [problem](/questions/tagged/problem) (just as an example)

What do you think?

Comment: relevant: [tag-cleanup 2012](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012)

Answer (score 4):

If a developer does decide to look into this, can we also get the editor to suggest other Stack Exchange *sites* when certain tags are used?  There are already several cases where Stack Overflow tags have split off into sites of their own.  A high percentage of questions in some tags are already getting migrated.  For example, [latex](/questions/tagged/latex).  Programming questions in other tags like [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) and [drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal) are still welcome on SO, but I think it's worth suggesting that non-programming questions with those tags be asked on the more specific SE sites for those topics.

Related: [Could we add “There is another SE site about this” indicator to some tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132628/1288)