# Could we add "There is another SE site about this" indicator to some tags?

Tags: feature-request

I've noticed that there are often questions on SO that don't really belong there, because there is a dedicated site for the purpose, but probably get asked because the user hasn't found that.

For example almost every question I see about SharePoint might be better answered over on SharePoint.se than on StackOverflow. I tend to add a comment to that extent when I see them, but I wonder whether it might be possible to add a clear pop-up or message when a user adds a tag like "SharePoint" to say "Hey, did you know there is another Stack Exchange site *all about this topic?*" in the same way we flag up obvious and catchable problems in questions right now.

It might save a bit of admin work in terms of moving questions between sites and help users to get their answers a little faster.

Comment: Any user (even 1 rep) can suggest a change to tag wiki - just do it, and two 5K+ users will have to approve it. Can't see any way of automating this..

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - I've edited the question slightly - I'm thinking about something more intrusive so the user adds the tag and straight away gets an in-your-face notification.

Comment: +1 - I made a [similar suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132504/1288) yesterday that probably should have been its own separate feature request.

Comment: We shouldn't be actively advertising other sites on this site before they even ask the question. It's just going to confuse people, especially newcomers, on where they should post their question.

Comment: @animuson But if they ask the question and then it gets moved, isn't that potentially more confusing, as well as meaning it takes much longer for the user to get a useful answer, which is likely to be the thing they most care about.

Comment: @glenatron: No, not really. It's very easy to follow the link to your new question, and it gets bumped to the top as a new question the new site, so it shouldn't really take any longer.

Answer (score 5):

That's a good idea, but I'm not sure that a tag wiki edit (as suggested in the comments by ShadowWizard) will be sufficient.  No one reads the tag wikis.  If this were to be done, it should be a dialog or warning in the question creation process to the effect of:

> You've tagged your question [sharepoint](/questions/tagged/sharepoint). In many cases, it's OK to ask about SharePoint on Stack Overflow -- but did you know that we also have a site at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ dedicated to this topic?
>
> In general, the SharePoint Stack Exchange site is preferred over Stack Overflow if your question is about
>
> - configuring your site
> - setting up permissions
> - adding web parts
> - using document libraries and lists
>
> Stack Overflow is preferred over the SharePoint Stack Exchange site if your question is about
>
> - programming using the SharePoint API
> - communicating with a SharePoint service from a server application you wrote in another programming language
>
> [Link to FAQ/SharePoint tag wiki for Stack Overflow]
> [Link to FAQ for SharePoint]
>
> Do you want to ask your question on Stack Overflow or Sharepoint?
>
> [Continue to ask on Stack Overflow]
>                  
> [Ask on SharePoint]

Note that I know next to nothing about the SharePoint site, so the bullet points above may be completely wrong.  They'd need to be carefully written in a collaboration between SharePoint users and users of the [sharepoint](/questions/tagged/sharepoint) tag on Stack Overflow.  I would have suggested using the discussion on [Area51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1055), but that post seems rather one-sided.

Comment: "No one reads the tag wikis" pffffff... Yup...

Answer (score 3):

You mention that you tend to add a comment whenever you see these questions.  That's great, but did you know that you can use a [tag filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101905) to get a list of these questions?  Tag filters greatly ease your task of watching this tag, and will allow you to add your comments to the questions which are most in need of migration.

For example, I am a user of the Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange.  There are a lot of questions that could be a better fit for our site which get asked on other sites, so I've created the following filter:

[image]

Of course, this approach has the downside that you have to manually watch the list and make the comments/flags yourself.  I created a simple one as a test, it looks like [Sharepoint questions not on Sharepoint](https://stackexchange.com/filters/44639/sharepoint-questions-not-on-sharepoint) gets about 8 questions per day.  Perhaps you can reduce that number and increase the level of Sharepoint traffic!

---

*Note: I've not been very dedicated in watching my filter, which gets about 9 questions/day.  Plus, a lot of the questions on my filter don't belong on Electrical Engineering.  Don't interpret the large number of questions still on that filter as evidence that this strategy won't work!*